# Windows 2012 R2 32-bit SNMP extension agent

Tags: dll, snmp, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to migrate application from Windows 2003 to Windows 2012 R2. There is a SNMP extension agent DLL (32-bit), that needs to be migrated as well.

I have installed SNMP service and tried to configure extension agent.

At first, I tried to do it in the same way as it was on Windows 2003 :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\ExtensionAgents` :

```
"1"="SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MyAgent\\CurrentVersion"
```

and 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyAgent\CurrentVersion` :
`"Pathname"="C:\bin\myagent"`.

But the extenstion agent did not start and in System event log I found this log :

> The SNMP Service is ignoring extension agent dll C:\bin\myagent
>   because it is missing or misconfigured.

The file `"myagent.dll"` is present. So I tried to add `"dll"` extension to registry key with same result.

After some Internet research I found, that registry keys for 32-bit applications should be under `Wow6432Node` sud-tree. So I moved the configuration to registry tree :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyAgent\CurrentVersion
```

and changed the configuration on extension agent to point to correct registry sub-tree. After this, there is no error log in System event log, but DLL is not loaded by any process (checked by Process Explorer).

Does anyone have any suggestions? (Recompilation to 64-bit is unfortunately not an option).

Comment: You need to recompile it as 64 bit and then the 64 bit SNMP service can load it.

Comment: Well, I did so. But with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with our 32-bit SNMP extension agent DLL which was solved by this way:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\OTES\NL_CUTDA\CurrentVersion]
REG_EXPAND_SZ : "Pathname"="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\OTES\NL_CUTDA\NL_CUTDA.dll"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SNMP\Parameters\ExtensionAgents]
REG_SZ : "nl_cutdamib"="SOFTWARE\\OTES\\NL_CUTDA\\CurrentVersion"
```

I think you do not have to change path to the registry subtree because `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` key is redirected to physical path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node` by
[Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(VS.85).aspx).